# How to load jquery Datatables into div with ajax call

Tags: jquery, datatables

I need to load whole table into div with `$.ajax`, but after that, Datatables won't work. Can i do something about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, the [liveQuery plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) could help in that case.

> Live Query utilizes the power of
>   jQuery selectors by binding events or
>   firing callbacks for matched elements
>   auto-magically, even after the page
>   has been loaded and the DOM updated.

Comment: I believe that this could be dont with .live() instead, isnt' it?

Comment: @Nik: The `live()` doesn't support plugins' cutom events/methods.

Comment: Hei. I figured it out. It was much simpler. I just had to put datatables code after filling result div like that: $.post(url, posts, function(data){ $("#results").empty().append(data); $('.datatables').dataTable(); });

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
  $.get("script.php",function(data){
    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
      $("#anydiv").prepend(item.element);          
    });
  })
})
```

In script.php
read array of database results into array and :

```
echo json_encode($results_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Datatable jQuery call needs to be made after the table exists - if you have it in document ready, the table won't exist yet, until the AJAX call is made - so put the data table initialisation in your AJAX function and you're home and hosed.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST", 
  url: "page.php", 
  data: { variable: variable }, 
  success: function(data) {
    $("#your_div").html(data);
    $('#yourtable').DataTable({
      "iDisplayLength": 10,
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      etc...
    });                        
  }
});
```